# jQuery: creating list from array not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am new to jQuery and especially to arrays and am trying to **create an unordered list from an array**. 
The array contains all unique values from certain parts of a table and creating this works as intended (tested via alert) but when I try to create a list with these values nothing (visible) happens.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?
Also, is there a way I can cover the case that the array does not contain any values and then just show a dummy or default item in the list ?

**Note:** `'#test'` is a test div where I was playing with this.

**My jQuery:**

```
$('#tblLegend td.col1').on('click', function(){
    var tblValues = new Array();
    $('#tblCalendar').find('tbody > div.editable').each(function(){
        if(tblValues.indexOf($(this).text()) == -1){
            tblValues.push($.trim($(this).text()));
        }
    });
    var ul = '<ul>';
        $.each(tblValues, function(i){
            ul+= '<li>' + tblValues[i] + '</li>';
        });
    ul+= '</ul>';
    $('#test').html(ul);
});
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: There no obvious wrong code.

Comment: can you replicate the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look.

Comment: Ok, I added a few list items manually and removed the $.each part for testing and it then creates and displays the list properly but not when I create it from the array like above. Unfortunately I cant create a fiddle from this as there are too many other things on the table here. Are you sure there is no error in the code above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#tblCalendar').find('tbody > div.editable')
```

Are you sure your selector ?
normally, the TBODY (body of table) dont may directly contain a DIV.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that fixed it ! :) You were right, my divs are actually within the tds so changing the selector to 'tbody td div.editable' covered this.